# Failing to display the string in Two Dimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am working on an application where I have to assign a specific value to a variable.

```
tU8 u8ADRPartData = 10;
char TunerArray[38][30] = {{0,"reserved"},
                            {1,"TunVar1 2FE DDA"},
                            {2,"TunVar2 1FE"},
                            {3,"TunVar3 2FE"},
                            {4,"reserved"},
                            {5,"TunVar5 3FE DDA"},
                            {6,"TunVar6 3FE DAB"},
                            {7,"TunVar7 4FE DDA DAB"},
                            {8,"TunVar8 2FE HD"},
                            {9,"TunVar9 2FE DDA HD"},
                            {10,"TunVar10 3FE DDA HD"},
                            {11,"TunVar11 3FE DAB SBM"},
                            {12,"TunVar12 4FE DDA DAB SBM"},
                            {13,"TunVar13 2FE DDA DDS"},
                            {14,"TunVar14 3FE DDA DDS DAB"},
                            {15,"TunVar15 3FE DDA DDS DAB"},
                            {16,"TunVar16 2FE"},
                            {17,"TunVar17 3FE DAB"},
                            {18,"TunVar18 2FE DDA DDS"},
                            {19,"TunVar19 2FE DDA DDS"},
                            {20,"TunVar20 3FE DDA DDS DAB"},
                            {21,"TunVar21 3FE DDA DDS DAB"},
                            {22,"TunVar22 3FE DDA DDS DAB"},
                            {23,"---"},
                            {24,"---"},
                            {25,"---"},
                            {26,"---"},
                            {27,"---"},
                            {28,"---"},
                            {29,"---"},
                            {30,"---"},
                            {31,"---"},
                            {32,"TunVar32 2FE DDA"},
                            {33,"TunVar33 3FE DDA DAB"},
                            {34,"TunVar34 2FE DAB"},
                            {35,"TunVar35 2FE DDA DDS"},
                            {36,"TunVar36"},
                            {37,"TunVar37 3FE DDA DDS DAB"}};

tString sTunerValue = TunerArray[u8ADRPartData][0];
cout<<"DISPLAY - "<<sTunerValue;
```

I am passing a respective tu8 value (10) inorder to make sure sTunerValue displays "TunVar10 3FE DDA HD". To be precise I can pass any number from 0 to 37 and store the respective string to display.

I am going wrong somewhere..... It says : `"error : invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive] {37,"TunVar37 3FE DDA DDS DAB"}};`

Please help :)

Comment: @RakibulHasan: I want to pass any value like '12' and display respective string "TunVar12 4FE DDA DAB SBM" in the array. I just want to store the string value for further processing :)

Comment: `{{0,"reserved"},` should be `{"reserved", ...` aso.

Comment: You may use `std::vector<std::string> TunerArray = {"reserved", "TunVar1 2FE DDA", ..};`

Comment: @Jarod42: I am new in C++ so concept of vector is not clear :) but I see I can learn from your approach. Any further help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the array like map. each entry in `TunerArray[38]` is a character array with size `30`. When you give some value to initialize, they will be automatically placed in order. You should use either

```
char TunerArray[38][30]; //declare
strcpy(TunerArray [0], "reserved");
////...insert other entries
```

or

```
char TunerArray[38][30] = { "reserved", .../*other entries*/}; //it will start to place the strings in order, from 0 to 37.
```

The error you see if because, you are trying to insert 0,1.. etc, where expects a *character literal*, and converts 0,1.. etc to equivalent character. But you can not place *character* in a character pointer array, hence the error.

If using array is not mandatory, I would recommend to use `std::vector<std::string>`, it will make your life simpler.

Comment: So If I do `char TunerArray[38][30] = { "reserved", "TunVar22 3FE DDA DDS DAB", "----", etc}; is enough? :)`

Comment: yes, you can, but better if u use vector.